"Traditionally, many shell scripts take the name of the program with the pid as a suffix and use that as a temporary file name"
man mktemp:

The mktemp utility is provided to allow shell scripts to safely use temporary files. Traditionally, many shell scripts take the name of the program with the pid as a suffix and use that as a temporary file name. This kind of naming scheme is predictable and the race condition it creates is easy for an attacker to win.

Could anybody show an example of such a file name? And where can I find such filenames "in real life"?

Searching Github

It's rather simple, really, a program called foobard running with PID 1234 would create a file called /tmp/foobard.1234 or so. It's hard to say how many programs would still use that pattern (I see one on my Mac)

thanks, ilkkachu!

The sentence you quoted in bold simply means that the created temporary file would be named
<script name>.<PID of the running script>  

in the defined or default temporary directory; e.g. under this scheme, a program called foobard running with PID 1234 would create a file called simply /tmp/foobard.1234.
Filenames like this are easy to predict, and an attacker could create a symlink with such a name pointing to some other file that would then get modified.

Note that this is not the format usually used by mktemp, which usually fills the last part of the filename with random characters.
E.g. the GNU coreutils documentation of mktemp says:

mktemp [option]… [template]
Safely create a temporary file or directory based on template, and print its name. If given, template must include at least three consecutive Xs in the last component. If omitted, the template tmp.XXXXXXXXXX is used, and option --tmpdir is implied. The final run of Xs in the template will be replaced by alpha-numeric characters;

and about the --tmpdir option:

--tmpdir[=dir]
Treat template relative to the directory dir. If dir is not specified or is the empty string, use the value of TMPDIR if available, otherwise use /tmp.


Before I came across mktemp (arguably before it was created in 1997) I used to do exactly this. For example,
progname=`basename "$0"`
counter="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$progname.$$.counter.tmp"
…
rm -f "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$progname".$$.*.tmp
exit 0

The progname=`basename "$0"`  construct is equivalent to ${0##*/} but I didn't discover that better replacement until just a few years ago. And these days I'd use $( … ) instead of the backticks.
The reference to counter in the file name itself is so that I could create more than one temporary file, if required, and the names would help me identify which one held what.

About the 1997 date, copy-pasting my comment to How create a temporary file in shell script?. mktemp originated in HP/UX with a different syntax. Todd C. Miller created a different one for OpenBSD in the mid-90s (copied by FreeBSD and NetBSD) and later made it also available as a standalone utility (www.mktemp.org). That's the one that was typically used on Linux until a (mostly compatible) mktemp utility was added to the GNU coreutils in 2007.

@StéphaneChazelas oh ok. very happy to correct the history if I've got it wrong. Did mktemp originally assume /tmp? I've a niggle it did
